# Function to Goto a Page in PDFViewer

Tags: java, android, pdf

I use [PdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)
Is there a function to goto a page ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After thorough searching and going through the documentation

```
pdfView.jumpTo(int page)
```

Does the magic.

Answer (score 3):

this may help you if u want to go on next or previus page in pdf

```
   public void next(View v){

     pdfView.jumpTo(pdfView.getCurrentPage()+1);//getCurrentPage method will 
     //return current page in int

   }

   public void back(View v){
     pdfView.jumpTo(pdfView.getCurrentPage()-1);
   }
```

Note, you can also pass boolean value which is of animation  in jumpTo method after first parameter

Answer (score 2):

I just checked out the first version of the library and there I found this function:

```
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
.defaultPage(1)
.load();
```

It might also exist in the second version.

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewerV1

Comment: I know about that function but its used to set the default page when the Library is called. I need a function that can go to a page. After an `OnClick`

Answer (score 1):

`pdfView.jumpTo(int pagenumber,true);`
It works with second argument "true" which is withanimation.